# Custom UITableCell has nil outlets

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Table view that I need to use a custom cell with a label and text field. I've designed the cell in the storyboard. I've set the custom cell's class to `ItemRowCell` and I've given it a reuse identifier of `itemRowCell`. I've connected the label and text field to the appropriate outlets in `ItemRowCell`.

This is the code for my ItemRowCell class

```
class ItemRowCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var itemDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var quantity: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

In my data source I have this code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemRowCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemRowCell
    let (description, quantity) = self.currentItems[indexPath.row]

    cell.itemDescription.text = description
    cell.quantity.text = String(quantity)

    return cell
}
```

Unfortunately, both outlets in the cell are nil.

Comment: Is the cell designed in a separate `xib` file? Or did you add it as a prototype cell in a `UITableViewController`

Comment: can you attach screenshot of your prototype cell and make sure they are connected well with ItemRowCell class.

Comment: Try reconnecting the outlets

Comment: Reconnected the outlets fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disconnecting and reconnecting the outlets fixed the issue.